# Joining 2 sql selects

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two very similar sql statements

```
select instrumentuniqueid, count(levelid) as errors
   from dbo.testevent
   join dbo.test 
   on dbo.test.id = dbo.testevent.testid where dbo.test.runid = 20962 and dbo.testevent.levelid = 1
   group by instrumentuniqueid


select instrumentuniqueid, count(levelid) as warnings
   from dbo.testevent 
   join dbo.test
   on dbo.test.id = dbo.testevent.testid where runid = 20962 and levelid = 2
   group by instrumentuniqueid
```

The first one produces columns of instrumentuniqueid (aggregated) and the count
The second one produces columns of aggregated instrumentuniqueid with a different count.

How can I join them together so that the final table looks like:

Instrumentuniqueid | Errors | Warnings

Comment: Move the differences from the WHERE clauses to CASE in the COUNT's.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 6):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select instrumentuniqueid,
       sum(case when te.levelid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as errors,
       sum(case when te.levelid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as warnings
   from dbo.testevent te join
        dbo.test t
        on t.id = t2.testid
where t.runid = 20962 
group by instrumentuniqueid;
```

Table aliases also make a query easier to write and to read.

Comment: I have a follow up question, i also need to sum up the total # of tests, but this can only selected from dbo.test. The query i use is simply select instrumentuniqueid, count(instrumentuniqueid) from dbo.test where runid = 20962 group by instrumentuniqueid, but im not sure how to join this to the other complex query

Comment: @Allen . . . I suspect that `count(distinct t.id)` would do what you want.  If not, you should ask it as another question, with sample data and desired results.